# mod_rewrite issue with removing .php file extension from a single page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I've been trying to remove the extension from a single page on a site of mine.

My code in httpd.conf looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^refer$ refer.php [L]
```

However, when I go to /refer, it says a 404 and that "*The requested URL /refer was not found on this server.*"

How can I rewrite only a single file in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this set of directives in a `Directory` block pointing to your document root for the domain? Is `AllowOverride All` set for that directory?

Comment: @AKor If this is in `.conf` file, then you need a leading slash: `RewriteRule ^/refer$ refer.php [L]`

Comment: @MikeRockett Yes, all of that is fine.

Comment: @DusanBajic Now, it goes from returning a 404 to returning a 400 Bad Request.